# Querydsl does not generate enum type fields in QFiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, querydsl

I am working on a Kotlin Spring Boot project with the following versions:

- Kotlin version: 1.7.22
- Spring Boot version: 2.7.7
- Querydsl version: 5.0.0

The project is built using Gradle version 7.6.

I added the necessary dependencies to use Querydsl and generated QFiles are created successfully, and most of the fields are generated correctly. However, fields with an enum type are not generated. I have tried rebuilding the project multiple times and also tried resetting the cache, but the issue persists.

I have also tried using both IntelliJ build and run settings and Gradle, and have tried with both nullable and non-nullable enum fields, but the enum fields are still not generated. Can you help me figure out what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your @Entity class?

If you are missing `@Enumerated` on enum type field, then try to add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` or `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`